# Laravel FatalErrorException on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4

I am deploying an laravel application in Google app engine. I have installed SDK and python. I can deploy it online, but when run application localy by using this command from cmd:

> python dev_appserver.py --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080
>   --admin_port=8000 --php_executable_path=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php-cgi.exe  C:\laravel-master

It shows the following error:

```
PHP Startup: apc_fcntl_create: could not open C:\Windows\.apc.a02796
```

I really need to run it locally because I can't test it online. Pls I need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cache having problems to send write file commands to your Windows SO. A workaround to this is to locally disable APC by adding:

```
apc.enabled = "0"
```

Do your SDK php.ini file.

But it's better to keep it enabled in your GAE application.